# Why is Perl inconsistent with sprintf rounding?

Tags: perl, floating-point, printf

Here is a Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @numbers = qw(
    0.254
    0.255
    0.256
);

foreach my $number (@numbers) {
    my $rounded = sprintf '%.2f', $number;
    say "$number => $rounded";
}

foreach my $number (@numbers) {
    $number += 100;
    my $rounded = sprintf '%.2f', $number;
    say "$number => $rounded";
}
```

It outputs:

```
0.254 => 0.25
0.255 => 0.26
0.256 => 0.26
100.254 => 100.25
100.255 => 100.25
100.256 => 100.26
```

For me it is very strange that Perl is inconsistent with rounding. I expect that both number ending with .255 to be rounded as .26 It is true for 0.255, but it is false for the number 100.255.

Here is the quote from Perl Cookbook, http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch02_04.htm,

> sprintf . The f format lets you specify a particular number of decimal
>   places to round its argument to. Perl looks at the following digit,
>   rounds up if it is 5 or greater, and rounds down otherwise.

But I can't see any evidence that it is correct in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html

Is it a bug in sprintf or Perl Cookbook is wrong? If it is desired behaviour, why does it work this way?

Comment: Seems also to affect `%g`: `perl -E 'printf "%.3g\n", 1.505'` gives 1.5, whereas `perl -E 'printf "%.3g\n", 1.506'` gives 1.51. Also both `perl -E 'printf "%.2g\n", 0.505'` and `perl -E 'printf "%.2g\n", 0.506'` gives 0.51

Comment: You are using two rounded numbers. Instead, use `say sprintf '%1$.19g => %1$.2f', $number;`. This will answer your question.

Comment: Re "*Perl looks at the following digit, rounds up if it is 5 or greater, and rounds down otherwise.*", This is inaccurate. It's entirely up to the underlying C library, which may not necessarily use that rounding method. In fact, on my gcc build, it rounds to even. (This isn't relevant to your problem, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl uses the underlying C library for formatting.  What this library does may vary from platform to platform.  Even POSIX says "The low-order digit shall be rounded in an implementation-defined manner."

In glibc, which arguably is used by the majority of perl binaries out there, the behavior you see will be affected by a couple of things:

First, as pointed out in another answer, the value you think is being rounded may not be exactly representable in floating point, and which way the rounding goes will be determined by if it is the next higher or lower representable number.

Second, even if the value is exactly representable as halfway between two possible roundings, glibc will use banker's rounding.  That is, it will round to an even digit.  So `sprintf '%.1g', .25` will produce `.2`, but `sprintf '%.1g', .75` will produce `.8`.

The quote from the Perl Cookbook is just plain wrong.

Comment: I would not say that the book was plain wrong. It says *"Perl's normal printing routines display numbers _rounded_ to 15 decimal places"*. So it was correct in that the numbers were displayed rounded, but it fails to mention the banker's rounding and that the rounding can be implementation dependent.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I meant the `Perl looks at the following digit, rounds up if it is 5 or greater, and rounds down otherwise.`

Answer (score 20):

If you add this line:

```
$number = sprintf '%.15f', $number;
```

before printing, you will have:

```
0.254000000000000 => 0.25
0.255000000000000 => 0.26
0.256000000000000 => 0.26
100.254000000000005 => 100.25
100.254999999999995 => 100.25
100.256000000000000 => 100.26
```

as you can see, `100.255` is not exactly `100.255` this is due to representation of float numbers.

Comment: More details can be found in [Chapter 2.3](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch02_04.htm) of Perl Cookbook: *"Perl's normal printing routines display numbers rounded to 15 decimal places or so, but its numeric tests don't round."*